# pandas using .where() to replace in .groupby() object

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Consider a dataframe which contains several groups of integers:

```py
d = pd.DataFrame({'label': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'], 'value': [1,2,3,2,7,1,8,9]})
d
    label   value
0   a   1
1   a   2
2   a   3
3   a   2
4   b   7
5   b   1
6   b   8
7   b   9
```

For each of these groups of integers, each integer has to be bigger or equal to the previous one. If not the case, it takes on the value of the previous integer. I replace using

`s.where(~(s < s.shift()), s.shift())`

which works fine for a single series. I can even group the dataframe, and loop through each extracted series:

```py
grouped = s.groupby('label')['value']
for _, s in grouped:
    print(s.where(~(s < s.shift()), s.shift()))
```

```
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    3.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
4    7.0
5    7.0
6    8.0
7    9.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

However, how do I now get these values back into my original dataframe?

Or, is there a better way to do this? I don't care for using `.groupby` and don't consider the for loop a pretty solution either...

Comment: If the second group were 7,1,2,8,9 would your ouptut be 7,7,7,8,9?

Comment: Good question, expected output would be `7, 7, 7, 8, 9`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) in the `groupby` like:

```
d['val_max'] = d.groupby('label')['value'].cummax()
print (d)
  label  value  val_max
0     a      1        1
1     a      2        2
2     a      3        3
3     a      2        3
4     b      7        7
5     b      1        7
6     b      8        8
7     b      9        9
```

Comment: I should have asked earlier, breaking my head over this. `cummax` is what I was looking for!

Comment: @jorijnsmit it is good sometimes to break your head over a problem, you won't forget the solution anytime soon ;)